# Fedex Special Rate Request using python-fedex

Tags: python, fedex

I am having a problem with fedex rate service request. I need to get the Saturday Delivery rate from fedex. How can i get this? I am using [python-fedex](https://github.com/gtaylor/python-fedex/) module.

I have tried using

```
rate_request.RequestedShipment.ServiceType = None
rate_request.VariableOptions = 'SATURDAY_DELIVERY'
```

with other parameters. Please give me some hints. I am just stucked with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know with that module. but a saturday delivery rate request looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v13">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <RateRequest>
         <WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <UserCredential>
               <Key></Key>
               <Password/>
            </UserCredential>
         </WebAuthenticationDetail>
         <ClientDetail>
            <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
            <MeterNumber></MeterNumber>
         </ClientDetail>
         <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId>RateRequest_Condor_Sat_Del</CustomerTransactionId>
         </TransactionDetail>
         <Version>
            <ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
            <Major>13</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
         </Version>
         <RequestedShipment>
            <ShipTimestamp>2012-08-17T09:30:47-05:00</ShipTimestamp>
            <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
            <ServiceType>FIRST_OVERNIGHT</ServiceType>
            <PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
            <TotalWeight>
               <Units>LB</Units>
               <Value>50.0</Value>
            </TotalWeight>
            <Shipper>
               <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
               <Contact>
                  <CompanyName>FedEx-WAPI</CompanyName>
                  <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
               </Contact>
               <Address>
                  <StreetLines>SN2000 Test Meter 8</StreetLines>
                  <StreetLines>10 Fedex Parkway</StreetLines>
                  <City>COLORADO SPRINGS</City>
                  <StateOrProvinceCode>CO</StateOrProvinceCode>
                  <PostalCode>80915</PostalCode>
                  <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
               </Address>
            </Shipper>
            <Recipient>
               <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
               <Contact>
                  <PersonName>Recipient Contact</PersonName>
                  <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
               </Contact>
               <Address>
                  <StreetLines>Recipient Address Line 1</StreetLines>
                  <StreetLines>Recipient Address Line 2</StreetLines>
                  <City>Minneapolis</City>
                  <StateOrProvinceCode>MN</StateOrProvinceCode>
                  <PostalCode>55411</PostalCode>
                  <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
               </Address>
            </Recipient>
            <ShippingChargesPayment>
               <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
               <Payor>
                  <ResponsibleParty>
                     <AccountNumber></AccountNumber>
                     <Tins>
                        <TinType>BUSINESS_STATE</TinType>
                        <Number>123456</Number>
                     </Tins>
                  </ResponsibleParty>
               </Payor>
            </ShippingChargesPayment>
            <SpecialServicesRequested>
               <SpecialServiceTypes>SATURDAY_DELIVERY</SpecialServiceTypes>
            </SpecialServicesRequested>
            <LabelSpecification>
               <LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</LabelFormatType>
               <ImageType>PNG</ImageType>
               <LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</LabelStockType>
            </LabelSpecification>
            <RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</RateRequestTypes>
            <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
            <RequestedPackageLineItems>
               <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
               <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
               <Weight>
                  <Units>LB</Units>
                  <Value>20.0</Value>
               </Weight>
               <Dimensions>
                  <Length>12</Length>
                  <Width>12</Width>
                  <Height>12</Height>
                  <Units>IN</Units>
               </Dimensions>
               <ContentRecords>
                  <PartNumber>123445</PartNumber>
                  <ItemNumber>kjdjalsro1262739827</ItemNumber>
                  <ReceivedQuantity>12</ReceivedQuantity>
                  <Description>ContentDescription</Description>
               </ContentRecords>
            </RequestedPackageLineItems>
         </RequestedShipment>
      </RateRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

where ShipmentSpecialServiceType is the important part to define -page 37 of the developer manual-:

> Identifies the collection of special services requested by the shipper
>   and offered by FedEx. the shipper requests a special service requiring
>   additional data (such as C.O.D.), the special service type must be
>   present in the SpecialServiceTypes collection, and the supporting
>   detail must be provided in the appropriate sub-object (such as
>   CodDetail).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped me a lot. Now i am facing another problem. May be all services or shipping address doesn't have saturday delivery special services available that's why i get 'Special Service Saturday Delivery is not allowed' error like this one. Thanks again. Great help!

Comment: yes of course... saturday delivery is not an option for all fedex services and countries. as far I know: FedEx Priority Overnight,FedEx First Overnight, FedEx Ground, FedEx Ground Freight, FedEx 2Day, FedEx 2Day A.M., International Priority, FedEx 1Day® Freight, FedEx 2Day Freight. But its important to check the country pairs in international, from argentina to US probably you could pay for saturday delivery but not from us to argentina.brgds

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Shiprush SDK. It has a SOAP entry point, and you can rate and ship for fedex and other carriers. (And they support it.)

Answer (score 0):

rate_request.derivedData.commitDetail.proofOfDeliveryDayOfWeek='SATURDAY'

This will solve your problem for python-fedex